# Получить отдельные параметры даты объекта Date

Tags: javascript

На клиенте в браузере получаю дату:

```
var day = Date(list.CreationDate);
```

`list.CreationDate` - это переменная с сервера, имеющая там тип `DateTime`  и приходящая на клиент `ajax` запросом.

Если в консоли браузера набрать **day**, то получаем

> "Sat Jan 16 2016 18:24:17 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)"

Т.е. вроде как **day** содержит дату

если в консоли набрать `day.getDay()`, то получаем:

> TypeError: day.getDay is not a function

Ожидалось, что получу число дня.

Что делаю не так?

Это нужно для того, чтобы распарсить дату и преобразовать её в строку вида `xx.xx.xxxx` **(день.месяц.год)**

Comment: `var day = new Date(list.CreationDate);`

Comment: если сделать так, то после ввода в консоли day.getDay() получаем NaN

Comment: Значит строка `list.CreationDate` не может быть преобразована в `Date`. Добавьте `console.log(list.CreationDate)` и `console.log(day)` и сообщите, что выведено..

Comment: console.log(list.CreationDate) - показало /Date(1452866810857)/      console.log(day) - показало Invalid Date, а если набрать list.CreationDate.getDay() - TypeError: list.CreationDate.getDay is not a function

Comment: На сервере - ASP.NET? http://erraticdev.blogspot.ca/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html

Comment: Igor, да, MVC стоит

Comment: в статье все подробно описано - http://erraticdev.blogspot.ca/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html

Comment: мм, спасибо Igor за статью. Но уж очень сложное решение там описывается. Там парсер сложно для меня написан, знаний пока не хватает понять. Может есть проще вариант?

Comment: там приведен javascript, который надо вставить в старницу - напрямую или как внешний файл

Comment: видно я туп. Не понимаю как использовать этот парсер. Попробую найти другое решкние. Спасибо Вам Igor, что попытались помочь!

Comment: Найдите в статье раздел "jQuery reusable extension that supports auto date conversion". Возьмите код из этого раздела и, для начала, вставьте его прямо в Вашу страницу между `<script>` и `</script>`, после тага `<script>` загружающего jQuery. (да, нужен jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте getDate() для получения дня месяца.

```
// a = new Date(list.CreationDate)
a = new Date("Sat Jan 16 2016 18:24:17 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)");
console.log(a.getDate() +'/'+ (a.getMonth() + 1) +'/'+ a.getFullYear());
```

Результат:

```
16/1/2016
```

Answer (score 2):

Это известная проблема с сериализацией даты. Когда дата сериализуется стандартными средствами получается строка следующего вида

```
 /Date(число)/
```

где *число* - это unixtimestamp сериализованной даты. Если это число передать в конструктор Date, то создастся дата соответствующая той, которую сериализовали.

Решений может быть несколько:

1. Выдрать число и передать в конструктор, например с помощь регулярных выражений

   ```
   new Date(parseInt('/Date(1452866810857)/'.match(/\d+/)[0],10))
   //Fri Jan 15 2016 17:06:50 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
   ```

   для случая из вопроса

   ```
   var day = new Date(parseInt(list.CreationDate.match(/\d+/)[0],10));
   ```
2. Отправлять сразу данный timestamp - это количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи (00:00:00 UTC) 1 января 1970 года. Тогда код упростится до

   ```
   var day = new Date(list.CreationDate);
   ```
3. Либо отправлять дату переведенную в [ISO формат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), в этом случае можно использовать не только конструктор, но и [метод parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

---

По поводу вашего варианта:
[В справке по функции Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> **Обратите внимание:** объекты Date могут быть созданы только путём вызова функции Date в качестве конструктора: обычный вызов функции (то есть, без использования оператора new) вернёт строку вместо объекта Date; в отличие от других объектных типов JavaScript, объекты Date не имеют литерального синтаксиса.

Таким образом, выполняя

```
var day = Date(list.CreationDate);
```

получаем в `day` - строку, а не дату.

Comment: №1 в одну строчку – риск, если `match()` не пройдёт.

Comment: @Sergiks, я подозреваю, что на клиент отправляется объект у которого поле типа Datetime, так вот оно _всегда_ в таком формате сериализуется стандартным сериализатором :-) Но да, на всякий случай всегда можно добавить проверки

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(list.CreationDate) - показало /Date(1452866810857)/

Если так, то, сам `list.CreationDate` – объект Date. Попробуйте:

```
var dateString = 
  ('0' + list.CreationDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'
  + ('0' + (list.CreationDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '.'
  + list.CreationDate.getFullYear(); // 15.01.2016
```

Comment: скорее _list.CreationDate – строка_

Comment: легко: `console.log('/Date(1452866810857)/');` покажет _/Date(1452866810857)/_

Comment: не совсем понял что имеется ввиду в последнем комментарии :)

Comment: Это известная проблема несовпадения ASP.NET JSON представления DateTime, с тем, что может быть распарсено на клиенте.